# Shell script terminates connection from server but leaves connection open

Tags: shell-script

I am creating/running a shell script from linux/Fedora server that is renaming multiple devices to default. Once it does the first device it hangs because the connection is not closing. the script is defaulting the ips and restarts the network service. How can I close the connection while that runs on the device?

Here is the script that resets them.

```
/bin/ssh $CHECKME -o ConnectTimeout=5 "/usr/local/bin/NameTerm.sh reset"
```

The `CHECKME` is from where I get the ips of the connected devices and runs fine. The `NameTerm.sh` is a shell script that sets the IP address back to 0.0.0.0 and then does a service network restart. I cannot alter the script.

Comment: Please post the script NameTerm.sh

Comment: does `NameTerm` do something that breaks the SSH connection or prevents it from working?

Comment: Yes, it sets the ips back to 0.0.0.0 and then does a service network restart. I cannot change the code within the shell and have to figure out how to "break" the connection once my script runs so it moves on to the next device.

Answer (score 1):

If the SSH server disappears, the TCP connection is still alive from the client's point of view, and the SSH client waits it by default.

The `ConnectTimeout` option makes no difference, as per the name, it's used when *connecting*, not when the connection is already active.

Instead, you probably want to use `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax`:

> ```
> ServerAliveCountMax
> ```
>
> Sets the number of server alive messages (see below) which may
>                be sent without ssh(1) receiving any messages back from the
>                server.  If this threshold is reached while server alive mes‐
>                sages are being sent, ssh will disconnect from the server, terminating the session.
>
> ```
> ServerAliveInterval
> ```
>
> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has
>                been received from the server, ssh(1) will send a message
>                through the encrypted channel to request a response from the
>                server.  The default is 0, indicating that these messages will
>                not be sent to the server.

This would wait for about 3x5 = 15 seconds, though `ServerAliveCountMax` is set to 3 by default, so you only need to set `ServerAliveInterval`.

```
ServerAliveCountMax 3
ServerAliveInterval 5
```